# Какой List оптимальнее?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Что быстрее и оптимальнее? Один большой `List<T>` (элементов так на 5000) или несколько  `List<T>`'ов поменьше (на 500,1000 элементов и т.д.)

Comment: Unity3D вообще ни при чем (хотя...), а несколько листов вроде должны быть оптимальнее, хотя надо тестить.

Comment: Оптимальное для каких операций?

Comment: Использую List для Object Pooling игровых префабов

Comment: Я бы посоветовал дек

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К **Unity** вопрос имеет мало отношения.

Тут роль играет лишь `c#`, в котором `List<T>`, насколько мне известно, является простой оберткой для массива.

По сути, он предлагает лишь удобный интерфейс, который прозрачно для пользователя расширяет массив, вставляет, удаляет элементы, ну и так далее.

Для повседневных задач использовать один лист оптимальнее, конечно же. Если вы думаете, что это эквивалент `лучше распихать предметы в две сумки, а то одна может порваться`, то вы ошибаетесь, так как в подобном массиве (коллекции) доступ к элементу производится **по индексу**, и вне зависимости от длины массива (списка) вы получите этот элемент **за одинаковое время**.

Конечно, если вы собираетесь часто вставлять элементы в середину списка (`Insert()`) или удалять из списка (`Remove()`), то вариант с несколькими коллекциями уменьшит количество копирований/выделений памяти и, соответственно, даст прирост в производительности, но, опять же, в таких случаях уже лучше использовать `LinkedList<T>`, что может дать существенный прирост производительности.

**Все вышесказанное относится лишь к общим случаям, и я не гарантирую верность этой информации для случая, о котором спрашиваете вы, так как я просто не имею понятия, что у вас конкретно за ситуация**.

Comment: @Scatman ну на самом деле для меня это все равно не очень конкретно, но если, скажем, вы хотите пулить какие-то пули, и при этом эти самые пули есть только одного вида, то используйте один список. Если нужно пулить объекты разного типа, то все зависит от ситуации, но я бы сделал список ключ-значение (у вас в c# это вроде бы `Dictionary` зовется), где ключ - вид объекта, а значение - `List`, являющийся пулом объектов соответствующего вида.

Comment: Да, наверное нужен Dictionary, у меня в List<T> два разных объекта с разной логикой